# Add dynamic items in bootstrap carousel /asp.net mvc5

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So this is the view :

```
e@model IEnumerable<CMSFC.Models.ContentHtml>
```

```
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @{int i = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            i++;
            var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";
            <div class="item @active">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "ContentHtml", new { Id = item.Id })">
                    <img src="@Url.Content(item.Ctl)" alt="" height="500" width="500">
                </a>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have problems with left and right controls , when i touch them , they are not affected , slides just move on automatically , but left and right controls arent working.

Answer (score 0):

In the left and right controls, you define `href=#myCarousel` instead of `href=#my-carousel`.